# How do I write to the SD card on Nougat/Android 7.0 (VR friendly)?

Tags: android, virtual-reality, sd-card, android-7.0-nougat

I'm looking for a way to make my VR Android app (for Samsung Galaxy S7 and S9) able to write files to the SD card (e.g. by downloading a .zip file and unzipping it there).

The app is mostly going to be used by people, who don't know a lot about Android/smartphones and don't want to have to deal with anything complicated (not necessarily seniors but close enough), that's why I want to make it as easy as possible for them, which also includes making choices myself (and setting it up for them) instead of showing complicated dialogs.

Special requirements:

- The files must not be deleted when the app is uninstalled - that's why I can's use `getExternalFilesDirs()` (Storage Volume).
- The folder everything happens in has to be easily accessable, so the zip files can be transfered to the SD card on your PC too (instead of downloading them through the app in case they are too big) without having to go down a huge amount of levels and remembering a long folder path.
- Using `Storage Access Framework` isn't a good alternative either because not only is picking folders nothing that's especially VR friendly but it also requires knowledge about folders most of the users simply won't have and/or won't want to deal with every time they open my app. But: If there was a way to only show this once (on the very first start after installing the app) and maybe even set the root folder to the folder I chose, so the users only have to hit "accept", that would be worth a try (unless there's an easier way).

Yes, I did set the `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and also enabled the `"force allow apps on external storage"` developer setting but trying to write to the SD card still throws an "Access Denied" exception.

Are there any others ways to write to the SD card that are VR friendly?

Comment: Set your `minSdkVersion` to 24 and [use `createAccessIntent()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageVolume.html#createAccessIntent(java.lang.String)). This pops up a dialog, but it is a simple permission grant, requiring only clicking on an "OK" button. Otherwise, as we discussed previously, there is nothing that meets your criteria that is documented and supported on Android 4.4+. For reference, see [the Android 8.1 CDD](https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.1/android-8.1-cdd#7_6_memory_and_storage) rules.

Comment: Permission grants are okay but as I said before (you deleted the whole post, so I can't go back), I can't use API 24 as the minSdkVersion, since the targetSdkVersion is currently set to 23 and I haven't tested anything else yet. What I was editing in right as you wrote your post: The (zip) files don't fit into any category "createAccessIntent()" gives access to (they aren't movies, pictures, downloads,...), plus with how many files the zip file can have, working with Uris is just impractical. In what folder/folder level would the zip files show up on your PC with "createAccessIntent()"?

Comment: "The (zip) files don't fit into any category "createAccessIntent()" gives access to" -- you can use `null` as the parameter to get access to the root of the storage volume, IIRC. "plus with how many files the zip file can have, working with Uris is just impractical" -- it is not significantly different than is working with files. In either case, you need to open an `OutputStream` on where an individual piece of content will be written. Whether that is a `FileOutputStream` or one that you get from `openOutputStream()` is not a major difference.

Comment: It's different enough that I'd have to change the whole app to support both "OutputStream" types and Uris. Do you know what the root of the storage volume is called (the path to it)? It's probably not anywhere near the root of the sd card (if it can even be accessed on your PC), is it (which won't meet requirement 2 then)? Something I just thought about: Is it possible to only show the Storage Access Framework" folder pick thing once (at the very first app start) and maybe even set the root folder to where I want the files to be stored, so the users only have to press "okay"?

Comment: "Do you know what the root of the storage volume is called (the path to it)?" -- by definition, that is not knowable, as it depends on the volume itself. "It's probably not anywhere near the root of the sd card" -- it *is* the root of the SD card. Just bear in mind that removable storage encompasses more than SD cards. "Is it possible to only show the Storage Access Framework" folder pick thing once (at the very first app start)" -- yes. "maybe even set the root folder to where I want the files to be stored" -- no.

Comment: If I used "createAccessIntent(null)", would my app get access to the whole SD card, which includes read AND write access, including creating a folder directly at the root ("sdcard/myfolder")? I know. ;) Hm, if SAF is only shown once, then that would be okay as long as I can somehow get the users to pick the right folder. Does this include writing access (for files & folders) as well, as long as I stay within that specific folder (which I won't have a choice of anyway looking at how SAF works)? Let's say they pick the root of the SD card, does this mean that I'll have full write access to it?

Comment: "If I used "createAccessIntent(null)", would my app get access to the whole SD card, which includes read AND write access, including creating a folder directly at the root ("sdcard/myfolder")?" -- it's supposed to. "if SAF is only shown once" -- in your case, that would require `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT_TREE`, which is for Android 5.0+. `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` works on 4.4, but that's not going to fit your needs. "Does this include writing access (for files & folders) as well, as long as I stay within that specific folder" -- yes.

Comment: So basically I can get write access to the whole SD card using both methods, either by using "null" as a parameter or asking the user to pick the SD card itself - and with both ways the files remain, even after uninstalling the app. Tbh I don't get the point behind the new system then if you can get access to the whole thing anyway. They could as well have created a new permission just for SD cards instead of having everyone re-write their whole code... I saw that SAF creates a "folder" for your app in the list of folders the user can choose from, can you prevent that?

Comment: "I saw that SAF creates a "folder" for your app in the list of folders the user can choose from, can you prevent that?" -- I do not know what you are referring to, sorry.

Comment: I'm talking about the extra "Your App" line [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaMUvV-gOfE#t=5m15s), can you prevent that from showing up? I looked at a bit of sample code for SAF, do you have to use Uris for it too (including "DocumentFile" instead of "File") like with "Storage Volume" or can you still use the other kinds (like "File") instead? If you can't, is the biggest difference between SV and SFA (at least in terms of what I need) then that the user can choose the folder he gives access to instead of simply clicking on a permission dialog?

Comment: "can you still use the other kinds (like "File") instead?" -- no. "is the biggest difference" -- IMHO, the biggest difference is the `minSdkVersion` requirement (21 for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, 24 for `createAccessIntent()`). But your description of the behavior seems reasonable. That video is for creating a storage provider; you are not doing that, and so that video is unrelated to your app.

Comment: Damn, is there any way to write to the SD card without using URIs? Okay. Oh, okay then...

Comment: "is there any way to write to the SD card without using URIs?" -- not that is in compliance with the other requirements that you have instituted.

Comment: "Damn" again! Let's forget the requirements for a second, are the folders you get with e.g. "mycontext.getExternalCacheDirs()" the only other way or is there still anything else left that doesn't use URIs?

Comment: "are the folders you get with e.g. "mycontext.getExternalCacheDirs()" the only other way" -- yes.

Comment: "Damn" again... I'll post again when I've made up my mind what I'm going to use. Thanks for the answers so far!

Comment: I tried doing it with `sdvolume.createAccessIntent(null)` and got it to show the permission popup ([click](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ScopedDirectoryAccess), doesn't show up in the app settings though like the normal read/write one) but what do I do from there? I need the names (actual names, like "myfile.txt") of all the files in "sdcard/myfolder" but I don't even know how to go down one folder level (or check if the folder even exists), let alone how to get the names of all the files in it, so I can filter out the ones with the file extentions I want, or unzip one of the files.

Comment: "but what do I do from there?" -- you get the `Uri` via `onActivityResult()` and start using it. For example, you might use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to wrap that `Uri` in a `DocumentFile`. `DocumentFile` offers an API that is a bit reminiscent of `File`, including `listFiles()` methods to get at children, and thereby traverse directory trees, etc. If you have further questions about how to use a `Uri` from the Storage Access Framework and related APIs like `createAccessIntent()`, it is probably best to start a new question.

Comment: Yup, got the URI and "permission granted" with `onActivityResult()` - I already had the Intent beforehand. Two more questions, which'll hopefully answer everything for now: 1. So you can't directly get the folder "myfolder" like you can with `File` by simply creating a new one and giving it the path but have to check every entry in the array `listFiles()` gives you? 2. Can I make the Intent/Uri only give me e.g. folders, .txt and .zip files?

Comment: "So you can't directly get the folder "myfolder"" -- try `findFile()`. "Can I make the Intent/Uri only give me e.g. folders, .txt and .zip files?" -- AFAIK, no.

Comment: Thanks, `findFile()` worked. Checking every file it is...

Comment: Sorry, another question: Is there a way to sort a `DocumentFile` array (without copying the names to a String array and sorting that)? `Arrays.sort(myArray)` only seems to work with normal `File` arrays.

Comment: Use [the two-parameter `sort()` that takes a `Comparator`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator%3C?%20super%20T%3E)), and write a `Comparator` that meets your needs.

Comment: So there's no built in method in "Intent" or ""Uri? Okay, thanks.

Comment: Something else just came up: How do you unpack zip files with the Uris? For the normal, external storage I use `import java.util.zip.*` but `ZipFile` wants the whole path and also doesn't take a `DocumentFile`. Is there any specific method the StorageManager/StorageVolume provides for this?

Comment: `ZipInputStream` works from an `InputStream`, which you can get by calling `getContentResolver().openInputStream()`. It's possible that `ZipInputStream` will have issues (e.g., wants to use `mark()` and `reset()`, which may or may not be an option on that stream), but it is where I would start.

Comment: I managed to get that far but I'm still not sure how to actually do the writing part. I just opened a new question about that that includes my normal (external storage) code and how far I've come so far. Could you check it out please - [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50329697/android-how-do-you-unzip-a-file-with-storage-volume-storageaccessframework).