# How do you unzip a file with Storage Volume (/StorageAccessFramework)?

Tags: android, android-intent, zip, unzip, storage-access-framework

I'm using this code (Android 7.0/Nougat) to unpack a zip file in external storage (including multiple folder levels inside):

```
try {
    ZipFile zip = new ZipFile(zippath);
    Enumeration enu = zip.entries();

    while(enu.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry zipEntry = (ZipEntry) enu.nextElement();
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        String fileName = null;

        try {
            fileName = zipEntry.getName();
            fileName = fileName.replace("\\",File.separator).replace("/",File.separator);
            int p = fileName.lastIndexOf(File.separator);

            if(p>=0) {
                File fd=new File(folderpath+File.separator+fileName.substring(0,p));
                fd.mkdirs();
            }

            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(folderpath+File.separator+fileName));
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(zip.getInputStream(zipEntry));
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
            int len = 0;

            while ((len = bis.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) > 0) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            bis.close();
            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

To get write access to the SD card I'm using `createAccessIntent` (Storage Volume) which uses `DocumentFile`s instead of the normal `File`.

I already did this to get a `ZipInputStream`:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getContentResolver().openInputStream(myDocumentFileZip.getUri());
BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(bufferedInputStream);
ZipEntry zipEntry;
```

...and I'm guessing that you continue like this:

```
while ((zipEntry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
```

But what do you do from there - how to you copy the files onto the SD card and still keep the folder structure like in the code above but using what Storage Volume (or Storage Access Framework) provides?

Comment: You would do it the same way that you would do it for files, except that you replace `File` and `FileOutputStream` with `DocumentFile` and an `OutputStream` that you get from `ContentResolver`. [Here is a secure recursive unzip class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/v0.8.0/security/src/main/java/com/commonsware/cwac/security/ZipUtils.java) that defeats some ways of creating malicious ZIP files. So, if I had to do what you are doing, I would clone this code and start making the replacements that I outlined.

Comment: It's okay, the files are downloaded from a secure server. To get the folder structure I now did a `fileName.split(File.separator)` and create the folders according to `split.length`. What I don't know is to how to even get the input stream for the `ZipFile zip` (starting at `bis = new...`) because I can't create it because I can't get the actual path but only the Uri. Also, `File` overwrites files, while `DocumentFile` creates a copy if the file already exists, can I change that to overwriting somehow (so I don't have to check the whole folder if a file with that name already exists)?

Comment: "What I don't know is to how to even get the input stream for the ZipFile zip" -- use `ZipInputStream`. This wraps a regular `InputStream`, which you can get from `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()`. "can I change that to overwriting somehow" -- not that I am aware of. But, if you are unzipping to a fresh location (a new document tree that you create), you do not have to worry about this scenario.

Comment: I'm talking about `bis = new BufferedInputStream(zip.getInputStream(zipEntry));`. The zip files have set names - if you re-download the same one, it'll have the same name and unzip into the same folder (but might have more or less files), so there's no guarantee that it'll always create a new file tree. Of course I could do a `myfolder.findFile("myfile")` but doing that for every file would take too long and doing it for just one or two (or 10) files wouldn't guarantee anything either. I guess, the best way to do it then would be to delete the folder (if it already exists) and start fresh.

Comment: @CommonsWare Do you know how to do the "bis = ...." part? The line above that I already did yesterday (`OutputStream out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(newDocumentFile.getUri()); BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);`) but I simply don't know how to integrate the `ZipFile` that I can't get in the first place.

Comment: @CommonsWare I got it to work, thanks, but I've come across a new problem now: If I unzip a file that was created with `java.util.zip` from/to the SD card, `zipEntry.getCompressedSize()` and `zipEntry.getSize()` are always "-1" and because of that my code only creates empty files. If I use a file I created with WinRar, everything is fine. If I use the code from the first post (so external storage), both files (java.util.zip & WinRar) unzip just fine. :/ Any idea what I could try to make it work?

Comment: Nothing leaps to mind, sorry.

Comment: @CommonsWare Damn, this has to be a bug then. I have to rely on zip files that were generated with the library and can't just pack all of them by hand. Do you maybe know of any other ways of unzipping with SV or getting the file size info?

Comment: I am not completely clear on what "SV" is. If you mean `StorageVolume`, then no. You could experiment with alternative ways of creating the `InputStream`. For example, you could try `openFileDescriptor()` or `openAssetFileDescriptor()` on `ContentResolver`, then use the underlying `FileDescriptor` objects to get a `FileInputStream`. It is possible that this will somehow give you better results, but it may not work with all `Uri` values (e.g., `StorageVolume` might work, but a Google Drive `Uri` from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` might not).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, I was talking about "StorageVolume". I found out what the problem is: `java.util.zip` doesn't set the `size` and `compressedSize` and trying to access them with `zipEntry` only returns "-1" (-> files with 0B). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3233600/2016165) post gave me an import tip: I don't actually have to check the length (going to edit my answer below), it automatically starts and stops at the right spots. A different problem with is that I can't set the progress bar in a dialog because I don't know the number of zipped files or the total/single file sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unzip with Storage Volume:

Careful: This way it creates copies if you unzip the same .zip file multiple times, while my original code in the first post (which you can't use for an SD card) doesn't but instead overwrites automatically!

```
try {
    InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(myZip.getUri());
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(bis);
    ZipEntry zipEntry;

    while ((zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        String fileName = null; 

        try {
            fileName = zipEntry.getName();        
            fileName = fileName.replace("\\",File.separator).replace("/",File.separator);
            int p=fileName.lastIndexOf(File.separator);        
            DocumentFile destFolder = myDestFolder; //DocumentFile of the destination folder
            String destName = fileName;

            if (p>=0) {
                String[] split = fileName.split(File.separator);

                //If the .zip file contains multiple folder levels, this is where you  
                //have to check and then create them, e.g. for 3 levels:
                if(split.length==1) {
                    destFolder = myFolder;
                    destName = filename;
                } else if(split.length==2) {
                    if(mySubFolder==null) {
                        mySubFolder = myFolder.createDirectory(split[0]);
                    }

                    destFolder = mySubFolder;
                    destName = split[1];
                } else if(split.length==3) {
                    if(mySubFolder==null) {
                        mySubFolder = myFolder.createDirectory(split[0]);
                    }
                    if(mySubSubFolder==null) {
                        mySubSubFolder = mySubFolder.createDirectory(split[1]);
                    }

                    destFolder = mySubSubFolder;
                    destName = split[2];
                }
            }

            DocumentFile df = null;

            //Now you have to tell it what file extensions ("MIME" type) you want to use, e.g.:
            if(destName.endsWith(".txt")) {
                df = destFolder.createFile("text/plain",destName.substring(0,destName.length()-4));
            } else if(destName.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                df = destFolder.createFile("image/jpeg",destName.substring(0,destName.length()-4));
            }

            OutputStream out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(df.getUri());
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(out);
            long zipfilesize = zipEntry.getSize();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
            int len = 0;
            int totlen = 0;

            while (((len = zis.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) > 0) && (totlen < zipfilesize)) {
                bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                totlen += len;
            }

            bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }

    is.close();
    bis.close();
    zis.close();
} catch (IOException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit: **Important**: `java.util.zip` doesn't set the `size` or `compressedSize` (will return "-1"), that's why this code will only create files with a size of 0B with zip files that were created by the library - zip files that were created by hand (e.g. with WinRar) work fine. To fix it, replace

```
while (((len = zis.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) > 0) && (totlen < zipfilesize)) {
```

with

```
while (((len = zis.read(buffer, 0, 10000)) > 0)) {
```

It's possible to do this because:

> the call to ZipInputStream.getNextEntry() positions the InputStream at the start of the entry and therefore supplying the ZipInputStream is the equivalent of supplying a ZipEntry's InputStream.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3233600/2016165

The disadvantages with this (in comparison to my non-StorageVolume version) are that you a) can't get the total amount of files in the zip and b) also can't get the (total) size of the files, which means that you can't set the progress bar in an "Unzipping..." dialog unless you iterate through all the zip entries first to count them.